# enclosing regular expression in parentheses in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

so i have a big list of items in excel. i copied them to Notepad++ because it has regex built in.

it could be AuAC21-XTS02L or BgUX20-C02S etc. basically i want to replace thses two with Au(AC21-XTS02)L and Bg(UX20-C02)S.

with the regular expression \D\D\d\d-(\D){1,3}\d\d i can perfectly find the part of the text that i want to enclose with parentheses but now i dont know how.

i tried using (\D\D\d\d-(\D){1,3}\d\d) as replacement but then i just receive something like Au(DDdd-D{1,3}dd)L.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70337684/372239) and add sample text file **and** expected result.

Comment: Match with whatever pattern you have, replace it with `\($&\)` to enclose with literal parentheses.

Answer (score 3):

You can store the whole matched string in a group and then replace that with `($1)`. Note that depending on your Notepad++ version you may need to use `\` instead of `$` to refer to a matching group (i.e. the replacement string would be `(\1)`)

Take a look at this Regex101 snippet: https://regex101.com/r/0e1Wcc/1

It will convert a sample input like,

```
it could be AuAC21-XTS02L or BgUX20-C02S etc.
it could be AuAC21-XTS02L or BgUX20-C02S etc.
it could be AuAC21-XTS02L or BgUX20-C02S etc.
```

into

```
it could be Au(AC21-XTS02)L or Bg(UX20-C02)S etc.
it could be Au(AC21-XTS02)L or Bg(UX20-C02)S etc.
it could be Au(AC21-XTS02)L or Bg(UX20-C02)S etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can take the full match `$0` for pattern `\D\D\d\d-\D{1,3}\d\d` without a capture group because that is not needed, and use it in the replacement between parenthesis `\($0\)`

The output will be

```
Au(AC21-XTS02)L or Bg(UX20-C02)S
```

**Note** that `\D` matches any character except a digit, so it could also match a space or a newline.

Looking at the example strings, at bit more precise match (using the same replacement `\($0\)` could be:

```
[A-Z][a-z]\K[A-Z]{2}\d\d-[A-Z0-9]{1,3}\d\d(?=[A-Z])
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VDzqDA/1)